# How to call a Generic method on a dynamic type in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, types

I have the following code:

```
public static List<object[]> Serialise2D_Rec<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
{
    int numElts = 0;
    foreach (var item in data)
        numElts++;

    Type t = typeof(T); // Get type pointer
    PropertyInfo[] propList = t.GetProperties();


    List<object[]> toret = new List<object[]>();

    for (long propID = 0; propID < propList.Count(); ++propID)
    {
        var proptype = propList[propID].PropertyType;
        if (proptype.IsPrimitive || proptype == typeof(Decimal) || proptype == typeof(String))
        {
            toret.Add(new object[numElts + 1]);
            toret[toret.Count - 1][0] = propList[propID].Name;
            int row = 1;
            foreach (T item in data)
            {
                toret[toret.Count - 1][row] = propList[propID].GetValue(item, null);
                row++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var lst = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance((typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(proptype)));
            foreach (T item in data)
            {
                lst.Add(propList[propID].GetValue(item, null));
            }
            List<object[]> serialisedProp = Serialise2D_Rec(lst);

        }
    }
    return toret;

}
```

However this line will fail with:

```
List<object[]> serialisedProp = Serialise2D_Rec(lst);
```

With the error:

```
****: error CS0411: The type arguments for method '****.****.Serialise2D_Rec<T>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

How can I specify the type in the recursion, it seems that the syntax for dynamic generic types is not that trivial.

Comment: What type is the parameter lst?

Comment: @HåkanFahlstedt: It's coming from near the end as part of the recursion; it's compile-time type is `IList` (non-generic)

Comment: Ok, as you can see in the answers there is a problem with using a non-generic type here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your type is dynamic, you won't know the type of the generic parameter until run-time. For this reason, you must also treat the function as dynamic, because you won't know the "type" of the function's generic signature until run-time.

You must use reflection to call a generic function dynamically. See [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method)

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this one.

Comment: @BlueTrin - Make sure to read the [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5134251/211627) on that question. Might be worth using for the sake of code maintainability.

Comment: This is really good stuff, I will use it when I get back to the office. In my case I know the most common types that will be called, so I could add this for the sake of having the check.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see a valid use case for generics in your case. Usage of generics assume you are able to statically identify the type on compile-time (or its ancestor, at least). Why don't you just accept the non-generic `IEnumerable`? If you do need to supply some base type of items in `data`, then supply it as a parameter:

```
public static List<object[]> Serialise2D_Rec(IEnumerable data, Type t)
{
    …
    for (…)
    {
        if (…)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            …
            List<object[]> serialisedProp = Serialise2D_Rec(lst, proptype);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Side note: use the extension method `data.Count()` instead of `foreach (var item in data) numElts++;`.

Comment: Duly noted, however I am still interesting in knowing how I can create the call to the method dynamically. BTW in this case I need T to get the headers correctly in the case the IEnumerable does not contain an element.

Comment: You'd have to retrieve `MethodInfo` for `Serialize2D_Rec` and the use [`MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx) to build an instance matching `proptype`. However, I doubt it's worth the clutter that will arise in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Get The Method by reflection
    MethodInfo serializerInfo = typeof(Serializer).GetMethod("Serialise2D_Rec",
                        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static); 

//Make a Generic instance of the type you want
    serializerInfo = serializerInfo.MakeGenericMethod(lst.GetType());

    List<object[]> serialisedProp = serializerInfo.Invoke(null, new object[] {lst});
```

Instead of **Serializer** in the `typeof()` put the class that hold your func Serialise2D_Rec

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like you can use generics in this case. The line fails because `lst` is a non-generic `IList` and it's passed as arguent to `Serialise2D_Rec`, which requires an `IEnumerable<T>`.

I suggest that you change your method not to be generic; it uses reflection anyway, it may not have a big impact.

Try this:

```
public static List<object[]> Serialise2D_Rec(IList data)
{
    int numElts = 0;
    foreach (var item in data)
        numElts++;

    if (data.Count == 0)
        throw new Exception("Cannot handle empty lists.");

    Type t = data[0].GetType(); // Get type pointer
    PropertyInfo[] propList = t.GetProperties();

    List<object[]> toret = new List<object[]>();

    for (long propID = 0; propID < propList.Count(); ++propID)
    {
        var proptype = propList[propID].PropertyType;
        if (proptype.IsPrimitive || proptype == typeof(Decimal) || proptype == typeof(String))
        {
            toret.Add(new object[numElts + 1]);
            toret[toret.Count - 1][0] = propList[propID].Name;
            int row = 1;
            foreach (object item in data)
            {
                toret[toret.Count - 1][row] = propList[propID].GetValue(item, null);
                row++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var lst = (IList)Activator.CreateInstance((typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(proptype)));
            foreach (object item in data)
            {
                lst.Add(propList[propID].GetValue(item, null));
            }
            List<object[]> serialisedProp = Serialise2D_Rec(lst);

        }
    }

    return toret;
}
```

Comment: I voted up your answer, but in my case I need it to work even on empty IEnumerable<T>, because it prints the name of the property in the first element of the Object[]: it is used later because the user is an Excel addin, so we print the headers of the name of the properties of the object even if there was no item returned.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's because `lst` is of type `object`.

You'll need to dynamically invoke the correct generic type of  `Serialise2D_Rec<T>()`

Comment: Well how do I build the correct type using Invoke and MakeGenericMethod ?